# windows 10 32 bit installation can't detect mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, 32-bit

I am trying to setup a dual boot computer win10 32 & 64 bit on a hp prodesk 400 g4. I could setup the option to be able to boot the 32 bit installer on legacy boot and it is working fine. The problem is that when the setup comes up the keyboard and mouse are not working. They are working in 64 bit UEFI mode and in the bios. The computer does not have any USB 3 ports nor PS2 port. Also I can not modify USB settings, just enable the ports. Can you help me what can I do?

Comment: You have 2 Windows 10 on the same machine. Do you have 2 different licenses?

Comment: "The computer does not have any USB 3 ports nor PS2 port." - If it doesn't have any USB ports how are you connecting a USB keyboard to the device? USB is backwards compatible, so in my eyes saying it has no USB 3 ports, is saying it has no USB ports at all.  **Most keyboards and mice are USB 2 devices anyways.**

Comment: 1. comment : Yes, I have 2 licences
2. comment: I said it does not have USB3 ports and PS2 port, I did not mention that it has no USB 2 ports. I clarified this because I saw some problem with windows 7 does not support USB 3 and there is a solution for that but in my case that would not work.

Comment: You have said twice now the computer does not have USB3 or USB2 ports and no PS/2 ports (normal today). What ports exactly does it have?  Have you tried a different keyboard?